# How to host multiple websites on a Standard Azure Websites Instance, Is this a Web Hosting Plan?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to host many websites in my Azure Standard Websites instance. Apparently one could put hundreds in, although I do not plan to.

As I understand it the "Instance" container is a VM, and web processes within these get recycled if idle. Are these VMs/Containers the same as "Web Hosting Plan", and therefore is the method to add a site to a Standard Instance via Add Website, Choose Web Hosting Plan and that is it.

So My question: Is "Web Hosting Plan" the same as VM Server/instance, and if so is my logic above correct for adding multiple websites to a VM Server otherwise known in Azure parlance as a "Standard" or "Basic" Website instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct.  "Instance" == Web Hosting Plan == VM.  Settings like the pricing tier (Standard vs Basic), autoscaling, and usage quotas are all set at the Plan level and shared by all websites within that plan.

This relationship is a lot more intuitive in the [new portal](https://portal.azure.com).

**Edit:**
[This article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview/) further explains the relationships between resource groups, hosting plans, and websites.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I am still in the old portal !! Perhaps a move is in order now.

Comment: But, in the others plan like basic? How many web sites in basic plan can I have to pay in a just only one instance?

Comment: Currently, Free: 10, Shared: 100, Basic and up: Unlimited.  See the [pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/)

Comment: Really nice! It's the same thing with SQL Azure Elastic Database, right? Lot of database in a single price. All I need to work with SaaS and multitenancy clients.